# Create tabe from mysql data with hyperlink to point to report page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok i am playing around with this idea for a system i am working on.  I want to display data from mysql into a table.  I can do this easy.  What i would like to do is this.  For the ID i would like to make it a link where i pass the id to the next page.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","username","password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What i want to do is in the (echo "" . $row['ID'] . "";)  I would like to convert it to a link so it would be something like this: example.com/report.php=24 or something like that.  What i need to do is find out how to pass the ID and also how to convert the echo to a hyperlink.

Also on the report page it will display all data for id=24 or what ever the id is into a form that i have setup.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a clickable link you use an anchor tag `<a></a>` In the `href` attribute you add the form name `report.php` and follow that with a `?` to seperate that from the parameter list. You then add `name=value` pairs after the `?` for the data you wish to pass eg `href="report.php?id=24"`

So to make the first page contain a clickable link you do something like this

```
echo '<td><a href="report.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></a></td>';
```

Now in the `report.php` script you access the passed data by looking at the `$_GET` array in PHP

```
<?php
    // check incoming params exist
    if ( ! isset($_GET['id'] ) {
        // missing param, go to an error page for example
        header('Location: error.php');
        exit;
    }

    // You can now use $_GET['id'] which will be the id number passed
    // any way you want.

    // For example using a PDO connection called $pdo

    $table = "table1";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = :id";

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->FetchAll();  // $rows now contains all the results of the query
    }
    catch( PDOException $e) {
        echo $e-getMessage();
    }

    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        // do things with the $row['column_name'] data
    }
```

Comment: i get the idea now for the link. What i would like to know is how on the report.php how to use the id in the url to run a sql statement like select * from $tbl_name where id = ** this is where i dont know how to set up the select statement and then how to do i use the $get function to add the data to the form can you tell me how to set this up. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is that any more help?

Comment: I do have a question if i need to use the get in text boxes from the code above how would i use that.

Example:

'<input name="water-purveyor" type="text" id="water-purveyor" size="35" value="<?php echo'.$result["forename"].' ?>" />'

also how would i use the result for a check box where if 1 = checked and 0 not checked?

Thank you for your help
@MayankDharwa

Comment: Take a look at the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) you use forms to process input fields

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It did give me some insight into the fields.  What i really need help on is how to show a check box as check or un-checked.  I think i could write the code i used for the check boxes but in a get method like this:

`<?php echo $caged = isset($_POST['caged']) ? 1 : 0; ?>`

would this work for a check box?

Comment: Checkboxes are only returned to the script if they are actually checked. So if  `isset(checkbox)` then it was checked

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
echo '
<td><a href="example.com/report.php="'. $row['ID'] .'">'.$row["ID"].' </a></td>';
```

Comment: Another member of the `try this club`. When answering it is a good idea to give some sort of explanation of why the OP should _try this_. Explain what you have done and why it is a good solution to their question

Comment: what should i explan in one link ? it's simple link which i added

Comment: i get the idea now for the link.  What i would like to know is how on the report.php how to use the id in the url to run a sql statement like select * from $tbl_name where id = ** this is where i dont know how to set up the select statement and then how to do i use the $get function to add the data to the form can you tell me how to set this up.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: here u take link as report.php?id="'.$row['ID'].'" ..so if u put isset($_GET['id'] )  then save that id in variable and u cn use that id

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using direct HTML for something like this.

```
<td><a href="somefile.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Link Name</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $link = "example.com/report.php?id=".$row['ID'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href = ". $link . ">" . $row['ID'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```